# Minister/Ministry of vs. Minister for

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

Does it make any difference to use either ***of*** or ***for*** after the word ***minister***?

Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English gives the following examples:

- *the Minister of Agriculture*
- *the Minister for Foreign Affairs*

However, this doesn't seem to work for the word ***ministry*** since the only preposition which has been used both in Longman and Oxford is ***of***:

- *the Ministry of Agriculture* (Longman Contemporary)
- *the Ministry of Defence* (Oxford Advance Learner's)

Comment: There is no hard-and-fast rule. Typically, foreign affairs is for. But other things can be for, also. But not everything would sound right. Also, bear in mind that mostly this is for foreign government departments (ministries) translated into English. In the UK and the US, we have secretaries as the head of government departments. We don't call them ministries.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in thinking *of* is usually used with Ministry

> [The Ministry **of** Silly Walks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ministry_of_Silly_Walks)

but it may also depend on how the title is phrased

> [Ministry for the Propagation of Virtue and the Prevention of Vice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministry_for_the_Propagation_of_Virtue_and_the_Prevention_of_Vice_(Afghanistan))

Ministry of Propagation.... would not sound correct.

I think your question is actually a more general question about the preposition rules for using either "*Ministry*" or "*Society*" or "*Department*" or "*Office*"

Certain wordings could only use **for**

> Ministry **for** the Advancement of...
>   Ministry **for** the Preservation of...
>   Ministry **for** Homeland Defense...
>   Ministry **for** Transport
>   Ministry **for** Use of Solar Power

and others could go either way

> Ministry **of** Trade
>   Ministry **for** Trade
>
> Ministry **of** Silly Walks
>   Ministry **for** Silly Walks

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it seems that, as Lambie has written, there are no hard-and-fast rules and they should be learn through reading and practicing. Do you have the same feeling?

Comment: I;e added some examples where it clearly needs to be **for**, but "reading and practicing" never hurts.